# Access denied connecting to Windows Server through WMI

Tags: windows, wmi

I want to connect to windows server 2019 through WMI.

I test the connection by Paessler WMI tester and I get 80070005: Access is denied.

I did the following but the problem is not resolved.

1. give access the user to root\cimV2 in wmimgmt.msc.
2. user is the member of Administrators , Performance Monitor Users, Distributed COM Users
3. user has permissions to DCOM
4. UAC is disabled by setting LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System
5. Remote client ip is added to trusted host of the server by following command in powershell:

- get-service winrm
  -enable-PSRemoting -force
- winrm s winrm/config/client '@{TrustedHosts="clientip"}'
- winrm quickconfig

6. Grant access to the user to connect from the network by configuring in  policy:

- Computer configuration > Windows Settings > Security Settings > Local Policies > User Rights Assignment: add user to Access this computer from the network

7. give WMI Access to client in server's firewall

Comment: Most of those actions are unnecessary due to the user is an administrator. You should include results of the local WMI test.

Comment: moreover it is not advised to disable the UAC for no reason. if its such a buggy application still needs it I wozld really think about it's age

Comment: I checked event viewer and following error created when I send a new request. The server-side authentication level policy does not allow the user user_name SID (S-1-5-21-1973546343-3298082641-2350970666-1018) from address 192.168.1.10 to activate DCOM server. Please raise the activation authentication level at least to RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_PKT_INTEGRITY in client application.

Comment: You should consider testing this remotely by using an actual WMI command. Dropping partial information amongst what is mostly irrelevant information isn't a good approach for symptom isolation.

Comment: Could be that the the user using passler and querying wmi needs to be a member of the the local administrator group. But i also see you setting psremoting,I don't understand why

Answer (score 0):

The problem solved by updating the client.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/kb5004442-manage-changes-for-windows-dcom-server-security-feature-bypass-cve-2021-26414-f1400b52-c141-43d2-941e-37ed901c769c